# Printing Inet4Address error

Tags: java, variables, methods

I have little problem with printing Inet4Address variable.

I got an 'The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String, void' exception.

I will show a part from my class:

```
public class Command{
    private Inet4Address A;
    public Inet4Address getA(){
     return A;
 }
 public void showConf(){
     System.out.println("Interface A: IP: " + getA().getHostAddress()); // there is a problem
  }
}
```

Any simple solution?

Comment: The error message would indicate that `getHostAddress()` has a `void` return type. That's probably not the actual code that's being compiled.

Answer (score 1):

The `getA(){` hade a `null` as return, try to create a `constructor` and initialize the `Inet4Address` in this solve the problem:

```
public class Command{
private String url = "google.com";

private Inet4Address A = null;


public Command() {
    super();
     try {
        A = (Inet4Address) Inet4Address.getByName(url);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Command().showConf();
        }

public Inet4Address getA(){
 return A;
}
  public void showConf(){
    System.out.println("Interface A: IP: " + getA().getHostAddress());
  } 
}
```

output:

```
  Interface A: IP: 64.15.126.118
```

Comment: This might be correct, but won't solve OPs asked question.

Comment: Thanks! That I was looking for ;)